# Null pointer exception for addTextChangedListener()

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to follow a tutorial for android development and when I try to run the code it is giving me a `nullpointerexception`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();

        billBeforeTip = 0.0;
        tipAmount = .15;
        finalBill = 0.0;

    } else {
        billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
        tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
        finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL);
    }

    billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
    tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText);
    finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalBillEditText);

    billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);
}

private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListener = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try{
            billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());

        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            billBeforeTip = 0.0;
        }
        updateTipAndFinalBill();        
    }

};
```

I have narrowed the problem down to the line with the `addTextChangedListener(`) in it but have no idea how to solve it.

Here is the log

```
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): Process: ie.ors.crazytipcalc, PID: 2052
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{ie.ors.crazytipcalc/ie.ors.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at ie.ors.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc.onCreate(CrazyTipCalc.java:56)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-01 07:00:23.450: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     ... 11 more
05-01 07:00:27.340: I/Process(2052): Sending signal. PID: 2052 SIG: 9
```

My layout code is

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billEditText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billEditText"
    android:text="@string/tip_text_view" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/billEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/billTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billTextView"
    android:ems="5"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/bill_edit_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tipEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tipTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tipTextView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipTextView"
    android:ems="4"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/tip_edit_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/finalBillTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tipEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tipEditText"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="@string/final_text_view" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/finalBillEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finalBillTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/finalBillTextView"
    android:ems="5"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/final_bill_edit_text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Make sure you have a view in your layout with the `android:id="@+id/billEditText`. If you do not, `findViewById()` will return null and you will get the NullPointerException on the line where you add the text changed listener.

Comment: what is line no 56 in `CrazyTipCalc.java`..???

Comment: @SilentKiller line no 56 is billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);

Comment: @user3592544 check the first comment given by Karakuri. that can be the solution

Comment: @Karakuri I have an `EditText`for the `billEditText`

Comment: What is the line in your CrazyTipCalc.java file with number 56

Comment: Is R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc the one listed? I mean that should be the Activity contentView layout, not the Fragment's.

Comment: @DoctororDrive thanks. Feel so stupid had the code in fragment layout rather than activity layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crashes because billBeforeTipET is null because findViewById haven't found it in Activity onCreate().

In this case make sure you set the layout which contains TextView with id billEditText in Activity's setContentView, not Fargment.

Answer (score 0):

i have made some changes to your layout file.. try with this one

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/billEditText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/billEditText"
        android:text="@string/tip_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/billEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/billTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/billTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/billTextView"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/bill_edit_text" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tipTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tipTextView"
        android:ems="4"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/tip_edit_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_below="@id/tipEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="@string/final_text_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/finalBillEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/finalBillTextView"
        android:layout_below="@id/finalBillTextView"
        android:ems="5"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:text="@string/final_bill_edit_text" >

    </EditText>
```